# Hermite-Bielher Theorem for entire functions

Tags: functions, polynomials, roots

In a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/781461/extensions-of-the-hermite-bielher-and-hermite-kakeya-theorem) asked by Bobby Ocean, the following theorem is cited:

***Hermite-Kakeya Theorem(for polynomials)*** - Given two real-valued polynomials, $f$ and $g$, then $f(x)+g(x) r$ has only real zeros for every $r\in\mathbb{R}$, if and only if, $f$ and $g$ have real interlacing zeros. (see Rahman & Schmeisser, page 197-199).

***Question*** Is there a similar theorem for entire functions as stated below:

***Hermite-Kakeya (for entire function)*** - Given two *entire functions*, $f$ and $g$, and $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ are real when $z\in\mathbb{R}$, then $f(z)+g(z) r$ has only real zeros for every $r\in\mathbb{R}$, if and only if, $f$ and $g$ have real interlacing zeros.

For example 
$$f(x)=\cos(\sqrt{x})=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{x}{((k-1/2)\pi)^2}\right)\tag{1}$$

$$g(x)=\frac{\sin(\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x}}=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{x}{(k\pi)^2}\right)\tag{1}$$

Thanks-
mike

Comment: By real-valued entire function, I assume you mean an entire function that maps $R$ into $R$. If so, please edit your Q , else  you may get some negative  or confused comments. I suspect the answer to your Q is "no".

Comment: Thanks @user254665. I edited the question as you suggested.